# Nothing to display on Edge Browser in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, browser

After opening the Google spreadsheet link, I encountered this issue with Microsoft Edge on Ubuntu 22.04. Any site I open displays a completely dark screen with no text or images showing. I managed to go to settings to try and change the theme but it did not solve the problem.

Below are the images of the state of my Edge Browser Now.

I have tried to uninstall and install it again but all to no avail

[image]

[image]

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on both Google Chrome and Edge, here is a fix I found:

Navigate to .config/microsoft-edge/Default/GPUCache

Remove everything in the directory and open Edge again. This should work.